# Getting python ctypes datatype from numpy datatype

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

In python, is there a convenient way of getting a `ctypes.c_*` datatype that corresponds to a numpy datatype?

E.g.

```
numpy.float32 -> ctypes.c_float
numpy.float64 -> ctypes.c_double
numpy.uint16 -> ctypes.c_uint16
```

etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes` seems to work:

```
>>> np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(np.float32())
c_float(0.0)
>>> np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(np.float64())
c_double(0.0)
>>> np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(np.uint16())
c_ushort(0)
```

Comment: That might be a good starting point. It give me an instance of a ctypes object, so I can use: `type(numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(np.float32()))` to get the datatype.

Comment: @DaveChallis Yep that's the idea. I had a look through ctypeslib but didn't really find anything more efficient than this.